# How to identify positive minimum or negative maximum in a column for a key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have the following columns - Person_ID Days. For one person id, multiple days are possible. Something like this:

```
Person_Id Days
1000      100
1000      200
1000      -50
1000      -10
1001      100
1001      200
1001       50
1001       10
1002      -50
1002      -10
```

I need to address the following scenarios:

If all values for days column are positive, I need minimum of the days for a person_id. If the days column has both positive and negative, I need minimum of positive. If all negatives, I need maximum of negative.

The output like:

```
Person_id Days
1000      100
1001       10
1002      -10
```

I tried using case statement, but I am unable to use a same column in the condition as well as grouping.

Comment: Please show the code you've tried.  Are you using postgresql or oracle?

Comment: Can 0 be a value in the Days column? In that case, if there is a 0 and also positive values, what should be returned? Probably 0... What if there are positive, negative, and zero values? Return 0?

Comment: 0 is possible in the column. It is okay to have it in result. @siyual - i use postgres

Answer (score 3):

Try this (Postgres 9.4+):

```
select person_id, coalesce(min(days) filter (where days > 0), max(days))
from a_table
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Person_Id, Days ) AS 
SELECT 1000, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000, -50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000, -10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001,  50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001,  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, -50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, -10 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT person_id, days
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY person_id
                             ORDER BY SIGN( ABS( days ) ),
                                      SIGN( DAYS ) DESC,
                                      ABS( DAYS )
                           ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

**Output**:

```
 PERSON_ID       DAYS
---------- ----------
      1000        100 
      1001         10 
      1002        -10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Person_id, min(abs(days)) * days/abs(days) from table_name 
group by Person_id
```

-- + handle zero_divide .. SORRY.. the above works only in MySQL .

Something like this will work anywhere which is equivalent of above query:

```
select t.Person_id , min(t.days) from table_name t, 
    (select Person_id, min(abs(days)) as days from table_name group by Person_id) v 
  where t.Person_id = v.Person_id 
  and abs(t days)   = v.days 
  group by Person_id;
```

OR

```
select id, min(Days) from ( 
    select Person_id, min(abs(Days)) as Days from temp group by Person_id 
    union 
    select Person_id, max(Days) as Days from temp group by Person_id
) temp 
group by Person_id;
```

Comment: In Oracle: `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` and in PostgreSQL: `ERROR: column "table_name.days" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 36`

Comment: It works perfect in MySQL with various data.
Sorry for writing some error.
You can of course change this.

Comment: Can't work in ANY SQL. WHICH "days/abs(days) is used in the formula? If you meant the multiplication is all WITHIN min() then it would make sense, but that would just be min(days) which is the wrong answer. Very unlikely that this can be made into a correct answer.

Comment: It works in MySQLServer version: 5.6.26  . Works Perfectly.

Comment: Did you test it with the inputs provided by the OP? Did you get the correct results? (Did the query even run?)

Comment: @mathguy, It perfectly ran and produced correct results in MySQL and produced resutls.  Please test my second query and let me know.

Comment: Btw, multiplication-based solution is subject to overflow.

Comment: It only appears to be working in MySQL: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I have given two other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle solution:

```
with
     input_data ( person_id, days) as (
     select 1000, 100 from dual union all
     select 1000, 200 from dual union all
     select 1000, -50 from dual union all
     select 1000, -10 from dual union all
     select 1001, 100 from dual union all
     select 1001, 200 from dual union all
     select 1001,  50 from dual union all
     select 1001,  10 from dual union all
     select 1002, -50 from dual union all
     select 1002, -10 from dual
     )
select person_id,
       NVL(min(case when days > 0 then days end), max(days)) as days
from   input_data
group by person_id;



 PERSON_ID       DAYS
---------- ----------
      1000        100
      1001         10
      1002        -10
```

For each `person_id`, if there is at least one `days` value that is strictly positive, then the `min` will be taken over positive `days` only and will be returned by `NVL()`. Otherwise the `min()` will return null, and `NVL()` will return `max()` over all `days` (all of which are, in this case, negative or 0).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using GroupBy clause in sql server. Take a look into below query:-

```
CREATE TABLE #test(Person_Id INT, [Days] INT)
DECLARE @LargestNumberFromTable INT;

INSERT INTO #test
SELECT 1000    , 100  UNION
SELECT 1000    ,  200 UNION
SELECT 1000    ,  -50 UNION
SELECT 1000    ,  -10 UNION
SELECT 1001    ,  100 UNION
SELECT 1001    ,  200 UNION
SELECT 1001    ,   50 UNION
SELECT 1001    ,   10 UNION
SELECT 1002    ,  -50 UNION
SELECT 1002    ,  -10 

SELECT @LargestNumberFromTable = ISNULL(MAX([Days]), 0)
FROM #test

SELECT Person_Id
    ,CASE WHEN  SUM(IIF([Days] > 0,[Days] , 0)) = 0 THEN MAX([Days]) -- All Negative
        WHEN SUM([Days]) = SUM(IIF([Days] > 0, [Days], 0)) THEN MIN ([Days]) -- ALL Positive
        WHEN SUM([Days]) <> SUM(IIF([Days] > 0, [Days], 0)) THEN MIN(IIF([Days] > 0, [Days], @LargestNumberFromTable)) --Mix (Negative And positive)
    END AS [Days]       
FROM #test
GROUP BY Person_Id

DROP TABLE #test
```

[image: Result]